# What exactly is the in-class-initializer?

Tags: c++11, in-class-initialization

I've read many text mentioned the in-class-initializer and I've searched many question on stackoverflow, However I didn't found any precise explanation on what is the in-class-initializer. And as far as I understood the variable of build-in type declared outside any function will be default initialized by the compiler, does the in-class-initilizer doing the same action for a declared variable?

Comment: For reference: You can find it on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) as _default member initializer_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example for in-class initialization. It's useful for less typing, especially when more than one constructor signatures are available. It's recommend in the [core guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c48-prefer-in-class-initializers-to-member-initializers-in-constructors-for-constant-initializers), too.

```
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo() = default; // No need to initialize data members in the initializer list.
    Foo(bool) { /* Do stuff here. */ } // Again, data member already have values. 

  private:
    int bar = 42; 
    //      ^^^^ in-class initialization
    int baz{};
    //     ^^ same, but requests zero initialization
};
```

As the data members are explicitly initialized, the second part of your questions doesn't really apply to to in-class initialization.